# Ideals of a number field below a certain magnitude

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm not very familiar with algebraic number theory, and right now I'm teaching myself the basics of prime decomposition (of course taking the route via associated primes and valuation rings).

I barely understand the definition of the norm of an ideal (Hilbert defines it as the cardinality of the quotient), and that the norm is multiplicative.

My question is the following:

> How can we prove that the number of ideals whose norm amounts to less than a given magnitude $x$ equals $C x + O(x^\alpha)$ with $\alpha < 1$, and what is $C$ (and, optionally, what is the best $\alpha$)?

In other words, I'd like to have confirmation that the order of an ideal at least does something like giving an index of that ideal, or, as it were, counting the ideals.

Unfortunately, I'm so unfamiliar with the subject that I wouldn't even know where to start. Obviously, I'd prefer an easy proof, but if simplicity must be sacrificed in order to view the proposition as a special case of a more general and intuitive statement, I'd be willing to do so.

Comment: Not what you're asking, but just to let you know that we even know how to count the [prime ideals with bounded norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_prime_ideal_theorem) in a number field.

Comment: I now wonder whether one uses the basis of an ideal. These are all in $O_K$, whence it seems to boil down to computing the norm in terms of the basis.

Comment: I've found one resource already: https://mast.queensu.ca/~murty/Murty-VanOrder.pdf